# Semi-formal valedictions in emails

Tags: politesse, salutations, email

How does one respectfully sign off semi-formal (e.g. business) emails without going for the full blown “*Veuillez agréer, Madame, Monsieur, l'expression de mes sentiments distingués.*” etc.?

Comment: See also: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/757/quelle-formule-de-politesse-doit-on-utiliser-a-la-fin-des-documents

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In business or university context, I tend to use:

> Cordialement,

Moreover, if I am thankful and want to convey this stronger feeling, I use:

> Bien cordialement,

Comment: I would complete by saying "Bien cordialement", is generally reservated for more formal discussions. (Student, teacher...)

Comment: To add on Zenlys comment: when the student writes to the teacher, he can write "Bien cordialement à vous". It formal and respectful, but not too much.

Answer (score 13):

I often use the adverb for *cordial*:

> Cordialement,
>       *<Here my email signature>*

For an “almost friend but not really friend”, I use something similar to *kindly*:

> Amicalement,
>       *<Here my email signature>*

Answer (score 8):

I often use:

> Bien à vous

or:

> Bien à toi

which is closer to *Yours truly* I guess.

Comment: I personally use *Bien à vous* too when I write an email in French

Comment: I find *bien à toi* disturbingly direct at the same time as formal. I'd reserve it to very close people, if to use it at all.

Comment: In short e-mail exchanges with a business contact you know more personally, you can also use "Bàv" or "Bàt", which are abbreviations for "bien à vous" et "bien à toi".

Answer (score 6):

Taking the first few mails in my inbox, we have:

> Bonne journée,
>
> Bonne fin de semaine,
>
> Cordialement,

Quite often, nothing.

But mostly, as this is the one included in the official company signature:

> Meilleures salutations,

Comment: Define *good* for *salutations* !? (It sounds contrived to me.)