# Quelle formule de politesse doit-on utiliser à la fin des documents ? — Which valedictions can be used to end a letter?

Tags: politesse, salutations, correspondance

Il existe de nombreuses formules de politesse ([salutations ou courtoisies](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocole_%C3%A9pistolaire#La_formule_de_salutation.2Fcourtoisie)) à la fin d'un courrier ou d'un e-mail. Cela va du simple « cordialement », au plus complexe « avec mes sincères salutations », en passant par des plus biscornues « veuillez agréer, Monsieur, mes salutations distinguées ».

Dans quel cas doit-on utiliser l'une ou l'autre de ces formules, et est-il possible d'en trouver une liste exhaustive ?

---

Marks of politeness (salutation or regard) at the end of letters and e-mails come in various flavours, ranging from a simple « *cordialement* » to the more complex « *avec mes sincères salutations* », and including more crooked ones like « *veuillez agréer, Monsieur, mes salutations distinguées* ».

Depending on the context, which of those is most appropriate? Is there a comprehensive list somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valedictions in emails](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27/valedictions-in-emails)

Comment: It is certainly link to the other question, but the other question precisely ask when to be semi formal and I need to know when to be formal!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- La forme la moins formelle est *Cordialement*. Je la trouve affreusement sèche mais dois reconnaître qu'elle est acceptée. Elle peut d'ailleurs être améliorée par *bien cordialement*, voire *bien à vous*, ou quelque chose du même ordre et [déjà expliqué](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27/valedictions-in-emails) ici. Cette forme s'utilise beaucoup pour signer des e-mails professionnels ou commerciaux, l'e-mail étant par nature moins formel qu'une lettre. J'ai déjà rencontré cette forme par écrit, mais j'ai trouvé cela peu avisé de la part de l'auteur.
- Ensuite vient *Avec mes sincères salutations*. Ceci est tout à fait approprié pour une lettre qui se veut polie mais sans formalisme excessif. C'est également approprié pour signer un e-mail, et c'est même plutôt agréable à lire. Un intermédiaire entre cette forme et la précédente est *Sincères salutations*.
- Enfin, vient le fameux *Veuillez agréer, [titre], ...*

  - *mes sincères salutations*,  ou encore
  - *mes salutations distinguées*
  - *l'expression de mes sentiments les meilleurs/les plus sincères* (attention à celui-ci ! Il s'adresse à une personne du même sexe uniquement afin d'éviter toute ambiguïté !)
  - *l'expression de mon profond respect* (cette forme est militaire), ou encore
  - *mes salutations respectueuses* (c'est personnel, mais c'est cette dernière qui trouve ma préférence).

  Toutes, sauf peut-être la formule militaire que je crois exclusive à ces derniers, sont appropriées pour signer une lettre écrite à un employeur potentiel, un juge, un avocat, un ministre, etc. Et aussi pour signer un e-mail dans le cas (assez rare) où il est rédigé dans l'esprit d'une lettre. Enfin, on peut substituer *dévoué(e)s* aux formes *distinguées*, *les meilleurs*, ou *les plus sincères* vues plus haut, si l'on souhaite affirmer une déférence hiérarchique par exemple.

---

- The least formal is *Cordialement*. I find it awfully plain, but I must admit that it is accepted. It can be refined as *bien cordialement*, or *bien à vous*, or [similar](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/27/valedictions-in-emails). It is often used to sign professional or commercial e-mails, which are in nature less formal than a letter. I came upon paper occurrences of this valediction, but I consider them ill-advised.
- Next comes *Avec mes sincères salutations*, which is perfectly appropriate
  for a polite letter that tries to avoid excessive formalism. It is also appropriate to sign e-mails, and reads rather pleasantly. A shortened intermediate form is *Sincères salutations*.
- Then the classic: *Veuillez agréer, [titre], ...*

  - *mes sincères salutations*,
  - *mes salutations distinguées*,
  - *l'expression de mes sentiments les meilleurs/les plus sincères* (be careful with this one! it is addressed only to a person of the same sex to avoid any ambiguity!)
  - *l'expression de mon profond respect* (military form)
  - *mes salutations respectueuses* (this one has my preference).

All, except perhaps the military form, are appropriate to sign a paper letter addressed to a potential employer, a judge, an attorney, a minister, etc. Or may be used to end an e-mail as long as it's written in the same fashion as would a letter. Last, one may substitute *dévoué(e)s* in place of the above-mentioned *distinguées*, *les meilleurs*, or *les plus sincères* to mark a hierarchical deference.

Comment: Et pourquoi ne pourrait-on pas avoir des sentiments les meilleurs et les plus ambigus du monde envers une personne du même sexe, je vous prie ? (Je suis peut-être d'accord avec l'idée, mais j'insisterai infiniement plus sur le fait que c'est un usage et non pas une évidence…)

Comment: C'est un usage, et pas une règle propre à la langue. L'usage compte autant que la règle, lorsque le but est d'être compris.

Comment: Usage qui tend à s'estomper dirait-on. J'ai reçu cette semaine une lettre professionnelle comportant "mes sentiments les meilleurs" de la part d'une personne de sexe opposée, ainsi qu'une autre le mois dernier.

Comment: Quand on n'a pas l'habitude d'envoyer des lettres formelles on regarde vite fait sur internet un modèle de lettre, sans forcément en comprendre les nuances et spécificités. Alors oui, l'usage peut s'estomper et devenir un peu n'importe quoi :)

Comment: @Shautieh C'est vrai :) Et en même temps, que cet usage-ci ("mes sentiments les meilleurs" aux personnes de même sexe uniquement, plus haut) s'estompe, ça me plait plutôt...

Comment: Pour les "sentiments", la règle que je connaissais était que les femmes ne devaient pas utiliser cette formule, quel que soit le destinataire. Les hommes, par contre, semblent en avoir le droit, toujours quel que soit le destinataire.
EDIT : You can also just say "Sincères salutations" rather than "avec mes sincères salutations", though it sounds slightly dry, it is used often. It's a level lower in formality, but still above "cordialement".
There is also "respectueusement" to be used when writing to doctors, professors, lawyers... people with high, "intellectual" professions.

Comment: I also read in several sources that "l'expression" should only be combined with "sentiments" and not "salutations" because "salutations" (greetings / regards) ARE an act of expression in themselves, unlike "sentiments" (feelings) which are expressed THROUGH various forms of language. But I've seen many many letters disregarding this rule, so I don't know if it's completely wrong or obsolete or if people just no longer know the rules. So you would say "veuillez agréer, Madame, Monsieur, mes salutations distinguées" without "l'expression".

Answer (score 6):

- Chez [abc-lettres](http://www.abc-lettres.com/formule-politesse.html) on peut trouver une liste de formules de politesse par destinataires assez détaillée.
- [Ici](http://www.poesie-poemes.com/formules-politesse.php) une autre liste de formules de politesse pour des courriers officiels ou personnels
- [Encore une autre liste](http://www.dicocitations.com/formule-politesse.php), avec des listes classées en fonction des occasions (réponse à des invitations, faire part...)

Answer (score 3):

A propos de Cordialement...

La plupart du temps en fin de lettre ou de courriel ce mot signifie : affectueusement, amicalement, avec bienveillance, chaleureusement, spontanément, sympathiquement…
Mais on peut aussi détester quelqu’un cordialement, lui vouer  une haine cordiale ou au contraire lui témoigner des cordialités affectueuses…le mot utilisé seul ne pourrait-il pas prêter à une certaine confusion ?

Le latin cord retrouvé dans cordis a donné cœur en français. Puis un synonyme coraticum a abouti à courage. Le mot courage fut longtemps synonyme de cœur organe essentiel « siège des sentiments » et même de l’âme selon Aristote. L’élément « cord » existe dans concorde et discorde, du latin concordia = « communauté de cœur » ou « communauté de sentiments ».

« Tout le talent d’écrire ne consiste-t-il pas  après tout que dans le choix des mots ? »

Une même formule de politesse et de salutation doit-elle achever telle lettre dédiée à l’élue  (ou l’élu) de son cœur ou tel courriel destiné à une administration fiscale ?
L’e-mail, cette nouvelle forme de correspondance, se termine très (trop ?) souvent par cordialement ….
Mais cordialement signifie étymologiquement, « propre à faciliter le  fonctionnement du cœur c’est à dire fortifiant, remontant, stimulant, tonique » puis  « qui vient du cœur » , « du fond du cœur », « avec tout son cœur » et plus récemment «  franchement, loyalement, ouvertement, sincèrement, spontanément, sympathiquement ». Même le mot courage fut synonyme de cœur puisque ce noble organe était considéré comme le siège des émotions,de la volonté , de la force. Un cordial, c’est à dire une boisson alcoolisée,  réconforte le cœur. 
La valeur du terme est donc intensive mais parfois existe une effet d’antiphrase  car on peut aussi haïr, s'ennuyer cordialement.
Peut-être conviendrait-il de choisir le terme selon que l’on souhaite exprimer une « communauté de cœur » ou concordance ou bien signifier une  « divergence de sentiments » ou  discordance. 
Dommage que l’on n’utilise plus la superbe formule épistolaire latine «e corde ad cordem »  du cœur (de l’expéditeur) au cœur (du lecteur)…

Le poète aurait-il toujours raison ?

Que les cieux vous gardent en bonne santé

Comment: +1 pour cette exécration [mot excessif, mais parfois on voue aux gémonies les automatismes plébéiens] que je partage, et cette magnifique analyse étymologique. Pour ma part je signe souvent *A bientôt*, afin de laisser la porte ouverte à un possible futur, même s'il faudra faire un effort pour lire la réponse.

Comment: Merci pour l'analyse étymologique ^^ Actuellement, "cordialement" fait référence à une forme d'amitié superficielle et je trouve quand même ça très pratique dans pas mal de situations. A éviter dans des situations formelles par contre, précisément parce que cela connote l'amitié donc la familiarité.