# Une formule de politesse de remerciement pour un service de l'État

Tags: politesse

Je recherche une formule de politesse pour le centre des impôts qui m'accorde un délai. J'ai pensé à « Merci de votre sollicitude » mais ils ne m'apportent pas de soin particulier. On m'a proposé « Merci de votre diligence » qui correspondrait, mais qui me paraît trop soutenu.

Est-ce que vous auriez une proposition plus adaptée ?

Comment: « Merci de votre compréhension », si c'est un délai qui t'es accordé au vu de circonstances particulières…

Comment: « Merci de votre considération », peut-être ? En admettant que tu veuilles vraiment les remercier — si il t'ont déjà accordé ce que tu souhaitais, ils n'attendant peut-être pas de réponse de ta part.

Comment: À quel point veux-tu être formel ? On a déjà traité des [formules de politesses](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/757/quelle-formule-de-politesse-doit-on-utiliser-a-la-fin-des-documents) et donné des pointeurs vers des sites les recensant.

Comment: @Un francophone: je dois confirmer une conversation téléphonique en envoyant une pièce jointe par écrit. C'est avant la formule de politesse finale.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*En vous remerciant de votre compréhension, je vous prie d'agréer (... blabla ...)* semble tout à fait approprié. 
C'est normalement soutenu, et c'est approprié à la circonstance.

Ou encore *Je vous remercie de votre compréhension et vous prie d'agréer (... blabla ...)*.

Comment: C'est la formule que j'ai retenue, merci.

Answer (score 3):

Une forme correcte devrait employer une phrase complète, et non *merci de/pour*

Remerciements: en général, on exprime des remerciements, pas sa gratitude (on s'adresse à une administration, ce n'est pas personnel).

**Formule de politesse appuyée, notamment si on sollicite un examen particulier d'une demande:**

> Je vous présente mes respectueuses salutations.
>
> Je vous prie d'accepter mes respectueuses salutations.
>
> Je vous prie de recevoir mes salutations distinguées.
>
> je vous prie d'agréer mes respectueuses salutations.

**Formule plus appuyée encore:**

> Je vous prie de bien vouloir accepter mes respectueuses salutations.

**Autre forme très respectueuse construite sur les précédentes:**

> Veuillez (agréer, recevoir, accepter, ...) ...

**Formule plus courante:**

> Je vous présente / adresse mes remerciements.
>
> En vous présentant mes remerciements.
>
> Vous remerciant.

Si le service a fait preuve de vitesse / réaction particulière:

> Je vous remercie pour votre diligence.

Si le service a été très sollicité et a donné beaucoup d'explications:

> Je vous remercie pour votre attention / compréhension.

Si le service a particulièrement assisté:

> Je vous remercie pour votre assistance.

Si le service a apporté beaucoup d'expertise:

> Je vous remercie pour votre expertise / votre professionnalisme.

Comment: Les formules qui n'utilisent pas le *Je* sont encore plus élaborées :  en effet, ce n'est pas mon petit "moi-je" que je mets en avant, mais *les*[mes] remerciements, la reconnaissance (qui est mienne) : En vous priant/remerciant... de/pour  ... Veuillez agréer, M...,  l'expression de mes sentiments les meilleurs (ou toute autre formule qui reflète l'estime que l'on peut avoir pour quelqu'un).

Comment: @cl-r effectivement, ce que j'ajoute.

Answer (score 2):

Avec toute ma gratitude, je vous prie...

Answer (score 1):

Je trouve qu'il y a une différence entre : *Merci de votre patience* et *Merci pour votre patience*. Avec « de » je vois plus quelque chose de futur (prospectif), une demande ; avec « pour », je vois plus quelque chose de passé et acté, une demande satisfaite.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French.SX ! Il est inutile de demander un avis lorsque l'on répond à une question (cf. [FAQ](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)). Il ne s'agit pas d'un forum et l'ordre des réponses peut changer en fonction des votes des autres utilisateurs. Merci toutefois de contribuer à notre communauté. :)