# Is this an appropriate salutation?

Tags: expressions, correspondance

When composing letters, I often use this as an opening statement (not including the normal *Cher ... etc.*)

> Je vous présente mes salutations chaleureuses.

Does this sound appropriate in French, or does it appear to Anglicized?

Comment: On présente ses salutations en général en fin de lettres. Some examples: http://www.lettres-gratuites.com/formules-politesse.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this does not sound anglicized at all, I do not think it is something someone would say as an opening statement.

Indeed, if we usually use *salut* as an opening statement in an informal conversation, a *salutation* in a letter definitely sounds to us as a closing statement.

In French, opening statements in letters tend to be really simple and concise : for example most letters simply start with a

> *Madame, Monsieur* in a formal letter or *Cher / chère* in an informal letter

French correspondence usually uses such formulations as the one you wish to use at the end of the letter, where you can also find, for example :

> *Je vous prie d'agréer mes salutations distinguées*

(You can find more of these in the answers of this question : [Quelle formule de politesse doit-on utiliser à la fin des documents ? — Which valedictions can be used to end a letter?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/757/quelle-formule-de-politesse-doit-on-utiliser-%C3%A0-la-fin-des-documents-which-va))

However, if you feel like you MUST use *Je vous présente mes salutations chaleureuses* at the beginning of your letter (which I would most likely not recommend), please note that in this context, it would be better to swap *chaleureuses* with *salutations*, it will sound more professional :

> *Je vous présente mes chaleureuses salutations*

---

If you are looking for other *formes de politesse*, as we call it in French, the link Laure provided is really useful and I used the forms provided there more than once when I was not sure about how to finish a letter ! Here it is : http://www.lettres-gratuites.com/formules-politesse.html

Hope I could help !

Comment: @AnneAunyme en effet ! faute d'attention de ma part, je voulais ajouter *l'expression de* mais je trouvais que ça sonnait vraiment too much ! Je corrige, merci

Answer (score 1):

As Laure said, salutations are generally put at the end of the letter.
[Her link](http://www.lettres-gratuites.com/formules-politesse.html)
However, you can ask how the person is doing, or wish her good, like that for instance :

> J'espère que tu vas bien, etc.
>   Comment vas-tu ?
>   ...

But your sentence is too close to the kind of salutation you put at the end of the letter.

Voilà !