# Une formule de politesse contenant « l'expression de mes salutations [...] » est-elle impropre ?

Tags: usage, politesse, lexique, salutations, correspondance

Dans des réponses à une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/757) on propose directement ou par l'entremise de liens des formules de politesse utilisées en conclusion de lettre (salutation) contenant « [...] l'expression de mes salutations [...] ». Il me semble qu'une *expression de sentiment* existe, certainement pas une *expression de salutation*, et que ça ne veut rien dire. Si c'était une erreur elle serait cependant courante...

Est-ce impropre ? Des sources crédibles, constatant cette impropriété, la remettent-elles en question ?

Answer (score 5):

Il s'agit en effet d'une [*impropriété*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/impropri%C3%A9t%C3%A9) (le terme varie pour la qualifier) :

> En français, on exprime des sentiments, mais non des salutations :
>
> - Veuillez agréer, Monsieur, l’expression de mes sentiments distingués.
> - Agréez, Monsieur, mes salutations distinguées.
>
> [ *Le guide du rédacteur* (Termium), [8.1.10 Salutation](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect8&info0=8.1.10#zz8) ]

---

> En français, on ne dit pas *agréer* ou *recevoir des sentiments*, mais
>   plutôt **agréer** ou **recevoir l’expression de sentiments** 
>   [...]
>
> À l’inverse, on ne dit pas *agréer* ou *recevoir l’expression de
>   salutations*, mais plutôt **agréer** ou **recevoir des salutations** :
>
> - Veuillez agréer mes salutations distinguées.
> - Recevez, Monsieur, mes plus cordiales salutations.
>
> [ *Clefs du français pratique* (Termium), [formules de salutation générales](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_f&page=9sItSGqits4A.html#zz9sItSGqits4A) ]

---

> Il faut noter que les formules *l’expression de* et *l’assurance de*
>   ne peuvent être suivies du complément *salutations*. En effet, on peut
>   exprimer des sentiments (d’où *expression de sentiments*) et assurer
>   quelqu’un de ses sentiments (c’est-à-dire lui donner l’assurance de
>   ses sentiments), mais ce n’est pas le cas des salutations (on dit
>   plutôt, directement, qu’on *fait*, qu’on *transmet*, qu’on *agrée*,
>   qu’on *reçoit* des salutations).
>
> **Exemples corrects :**
>
> Agréez, Mesdames, Messieurs, mes salutations distinguées.
>   Veuillez agréer, Madame, l’expression de mes sentiments
>   distingués.
>  Je vous prie d’agréer, Monsieur, l’assurance de mes
>   meilleurs sentiments.
>  Je vous prie de recevoir, Madame, mes plus
>   cordiales salutations.
>
> **Exemples fautifs :**
>
> Agréez, Mesdames, Messieurs, l’expression de mes salutations
>   distinguées.
>  Je vous prie de recevoir, Madame, l’assurance de mes
>   plus cordiales salutations.
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique* (OQLF), [Salutation](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2101) ]

---

> L’Académie française n’exerce aucun magistère en matière de codes
>   sociaux : elle ne saurait en aucun cas constituer une « autorité
>   officielle » concernant les formules de politesse. Ces dernières
>   relèvent des usages, des bonnes manières et certains ouvrages, qui se
>   disent spécialistes en la matière, peuvent se contredire les uns les
>   autres. On s’accorde néanmoins pour dire que le verbe *agréer* peut
>   introduire les termes *d’expression* ou *d’assurance* : *veuillez
>   agréer l’expression de mes hommages, de mes respects, l’assurance de
>   ma considération*. En revanche la forme « expression de mes
>   salutations distinguées » est considérée comme incorrecte : on ne peut
>   transmettre que l’expression d’un sentiment, d’une attitude (*respect,
>   hommage,* etc.). On peut seulement dire « (…) *agréer mes salutations*
>   » (« l’expression de mes salutations » est une sorte de non-sens).
>
> [ *Académie française*, [Courrier des internautes](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/estelle-d-toulouse) (Estelle D. (Toulouse)) ]

Je ne dispose pas des sources crédibles sur papier qui me permettraient d'affirmer qu'on en discute et qu'on remet ça en question. Je note qu'une [*salutation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/salutation) est une *action* et je trouve incongru pour une personne d'exprimer une action, d'où le fait que je trouve intelligent le propos de l'Académie, et je remarque au passage que l'exemple présenté au TLFi à *formule de salutation/salutations* est conforme aux énoncés contenus dans les sources précédentes.

Comment: Veuille agréer l'expression de mon cordial commentaire... ;-)

Comment: Le downvoteur n'aura peut-être pas compris le deuxième degré de mon commentaire. C'est le côté parfois frustrant de la "démocratie" : *one man, one vote*...

Comment: @jlliagre: comment voit-on les downvotes? sur SO on peut cliquer sur le score et en voir la décomposition mais cela ne fonctionne pas ici (à moins que je n'aie pas encore le charisme necessaire, ce qui peut prendre du temps vu le peu de trafic sur cet exchange.

Comment: @chqrlie Pareil que sur SO et c'est bien en fonction de son "charisme". Il faut être un [*established user*](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) pour décomposer le score d'une question ou d'une réponse. Sur FSE, le seuil est de 750 points alors que c'est 1000 sur SO.