# What is the most appropriate translation of "Best regards"?

Tags: questions

At work, I will email someone at a higher level who I respect, but what is the most appropriate translation of "Best regards" in this situation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quelle formule de politesse doit-on utiliser à la fin des documents ? — Which valedictions can be used to end a letter?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/757/quelle-formule-de-politesse-doit-on-utiliser-%c3%a0-la-fin-des-documents-which-va)

Comment: You can use: Très cordialement is polite and does not sound old-fashioned. It is very used in business.

Answer (score 1):

Just use ***Cordialement***, like mostly everyone does within the same organization or in a business context.

It is short, neither too formal nor too informal, a *formule passe-partout*.

Comment: When I want to add another level, I generally use "bien cordialement"

Answer (score 0):

I use these two often in my emails

**Veuillez agréer, Madame/Monsieur, l’expression de mon profond respect.**

**Veuillez agréer, Madame/Monsieur, mes salutations distinguées.**

Comment: What do you think about "Meilleures salutations"

Comment: @user2874061 It seems a bit 'cold' if I could say. It doesn't really express your respect as you said. 'Meilleur' can be used in ''Meilleurs vœux'' meaning ''Best wishes''.

Comment: I believe that those 2 expressions denote a higher level of formality than 'best regard'